# Reactjs massaging the data from two different prop fields in a map function

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, react-props

just had a question about massaging the data from a map function in React Js. I have a table that I am trying to populate using the map function. Its populating data from the dummy "accounts" prop data I have supplied. However, some of the necessary would need to be fetched in another prop called "holdingsByAccount" for example  . I have researched other methods but am not sure how to implement it and put it to use in this case.

Comment: Are you wanting to combine the props data, and then map over the combined data?

Comment: Hey, yep! Thats what im trying to do

Comment: whats the output of the data if you concat the props `let combinedProps = [].concat(accounts, holdingByAccounts);` Try and console log that

Comment: What is the output you want from the two combined props. I can't see all the data. You can right click in the inspector on the array hit store as global variable and copy to your clipboard with copy(temp1) which is the stored global variable. It would be easier to see the array in its full format